# Как можно сделать через массив чтоб когда я ввожу номер телефона к пример:380952288100 он выводиться в формате (380)95-22-88-100

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Phone_number {

public:
    int code;
    string number;
    string type_number;
    //Конструктор для копирования
    Phone_number(const Phone_number& v) :
        code(v.code),
        number(v.number),
        type_number(v.type_number) {}
    //Конструктор для сравнения
    const Phone_number& operator=(const Phone_number& v)
    {
        code = v.code;
        number = v.number;
        type_number = v.type_number;
        return v;
    }
    //Простой конструктор
    Phone_number() {}
};
int main() {
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    int tel = 1;

    Phone_number* Phone1 = new Phone_number[tel];
    cout << "Enter Telephone number" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < tel; i++) {
        cin >> Phone1[i].number;
    }
    



}
```

Comment: Копируйте посимвольно, вставляя нужные разделители в нужных местах...

Comment: ну а как это в коде сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

> а как это в коде сделать?

Да хоть самым тупым способом:

```
string dash(const string& s)
{
    string r;
    for(int i = s.size(); i-->0; )
    {
        r = s[i] + r;
        switch(s.size()-i)
        {
        case 3: case 5: case 7: r = '-' + r; break;
        case 9: r = ')' + r; break;
        }
    }
    return '(' + r;
}

int main()
{
    cout << dash("380952288100");
}
```